# A correct pairs function in TypeScript or FlowType?

Tags: typescript, types, flowtype

I have written the following implementation of a pairs function to the best of my knowledge of TypeScript:

```
const pairs = <A, B extends keyof A>(a: A): [keyof A, A[B]][] => {
  const mapper = (k: keyof A): [keyof A, A[B]] => [k, a[k]]
  return Object.keys(a).map(mapper)
}
```

The issue is that it does not preserve valid combinations, for example:

```
const myPairs = pairs({ a: 1, b: false, c: "a" })
```

returns type:

```
type MyPairs = Array<["a" | "b" | "c", string | number | boolean]>
```

while what would be correct is actually:

```
type MyPairs = Array<["a", number] | ["b", boolean] | ["c", string]>
```

Consequently I can do nasty things like:

```
myPairs.push(["a", "BUG"]) // This type checks
```

How would a version of `pairs` be written in either TypeScript or FlowType that produces the desired return type?

--Edit

Here is a picture of the current proposed solution not working in my editor.

[image]

Comment: I wrote a little post about this quest: https://blog.jasonkuhrt.com/logs/10-writing-pairs-in-typescript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want this return type:

```
type MyPairs = Array<['a', number] | ['b', boolean] | ['c', string]>
```

you could make a mapped type for it like this:

```
type Pairs<T> = Array<{
    [P in keyof T]: [P, T[P]]
}[keyof T]>
```

and implement your method like this:

```
const pairs = <A extends Record<string, any>>(a: A): Pairs<A> => {
    return Object.keys(a).map((k) => [k, a[k]]) as any;
}
```

or even simpler if you target ES6:

```
const pairs = <A>(a: A): Pairs<A> => {
    return Object.entries(a) as any;
}
```

**[Working Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Pairs%3CT%3E%20%3D%20Array%3C%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20%5BP%2C%20T%5BP%5D%5D%0D%0A%7D%5Bkeyof%20T%5D%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20pairs%20%3D%20%3CA%20extends%20Record%3Cstring%2C%20any%3E%3E(a%3A%20A)%3A%20Pairs%3CA%3E%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Object.keys(a).map((k)%20%3D%3E%20%5Bk%2C%20a%5Bk%5D%5D)%20as%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20myPairs%20%3D%20pairs(%7B%20a%3A%201%2C%20b%3A%20false%2C%20c%3A%20%22a%22%20%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0AmyPairs.push(%5B'a'%2C%2042%5D)%0D%0AmyPairs.push(%5B'a'%2C%20'BUG'%5D)%0D%0A)**

Comment: Fixed the "desired type" in my question. Slip on my part last night. You presumed perfectly what I meant though thanks : )

Comment: I don't know why it is not working for you. I added a link to a working playground in the answer.

Comment: Hm, I checked your answer in the playground (I can't put shorten'd url here and link itself is too long too...) and it seems to work. However the exact same code in my editor does not work. I am using TS 2.6.2 in my project. I assume TS playground is too. Any idea?

Comment: Thanks Tao yeah did the same.

Comment: Playground is on 2.6.1-insiders.20171019 but I also tested it local with 2.6.2. Which editor are you using? Maybe the editor is using an older ts version for analyzing the syntax?

Comment: Ah the issue is with Atom IDE's TS package using its own version of TS https://github.com/atom/ide-typescript/issues/22. I switched to the other main TS package for Atom and its all good now. Thanks! One other thought... I replaced the `any` usage with `const mapper = (k: keyof A): Pairs<A> => [k, a[k]]` but found only `const mapper = (k: keyof A): [keyof A, A[keyof A]] => [k, a[k]]` works.